# Printer online and enabled - receives job but doesn't print

Tags: linux, centos, cups

I have setup a printer with the command `lpadmin -p printername -o printer-error-policy=retry-current-job -E -v lpd://printername/RAW?timeout=10`.

The printer is detected and enabled. However, when I do a test print with the command `lp -d svstkctl1 test.txt`, the printer says processing but doesn't print anything. So it is receiving the message from the server.

The server I am trying to print from is CentOS 6.7 running CUPS 1.4.2. The printer is an EPSON WF-4830.

Comment: Do you have the same issue using the printer as a port 9100 RAW printer? Use `socket://printername:9100` instead of LPD.

Comment: lpadmin -p PrinterName -E -v lpd://server name/queue name. I am using the queue name RAW. Could this be the reason why it's not working on this printer? Can the queue name be anything? I'll try sockets also and see if it works.

Comment: Please use Jetdirect Socket printing if the printer is capable.

Answer (score 0):

The queue name is specified by the printer, not the client. Most of the time, the name of this queue is 'lp'. So you might want to try `lpadmin -p PrinterName -E -v lpd://printer_hostname/lp`.

If that doesn't work, try using a socket with `lpadmin -P PrinterName -E -v socket://printer_hostname:9100/`.

Comment: Same thing, printer says processing and then completes but doesn't print anything.

Comment: Raw printing won't work with this printer.  You need to go obtain the [proprietary printer driver](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) from Epson.  Enter WF-4830 in the search box.

Comment: I contacted Epson and they said it did support RAW printing. Unfortunately, they couldn't support me further as they don't support Linux. Epson does not provide a driver for Linux for this model. Do I need to configure RAW on this printer or set the right print queue?

Comment: The link in my previous comment is for the Epson Linux driver for that printer. A search of the linuxprinting.org forums reveals that the printer, like almost every printer in Epson's lineup, speaks ESC-P/2 and not PostScript. Supporting RAW printing doesn't necessarily mean it supports driverless printing, just that it supports JetDirect printing via a TCP socket on port 9100. It's still up to you to get the data that arrives into the correct format.

Comment: There's no drivers for CentOS 6.6 as it's reached end-of-life. I'm able to print to some printer without specifying the drivers using either JetDirect or LPD. So does this mean I am using a generic/text driver to print documents when using LPD/JetDirect? From my understanding, the communication with the printer can be RAW/LPD and the formatting is done by the driver?

Comment: When I don't specify a driver with lpadmin command, which driver will CentOS use? Will it be a PCL5 or PCL6 driver?